# Removing opacity from children class

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I created a small lightbox script, the script itself works fine but the problem is that the `lightbox` class which is filling up the whole screen needs to be translucent and if I make it that, the `lightbox-image` becomes translucent as well. I tried adding `opacity: 1;` to the `lightbox-image` but it didn't work. Can you help?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="lightbox-image">
        <p>Something here</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

.lightbox-image {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because the parent has `opacity:0.9` , so all the children will inherit this property (and you can't assign different opacity to children). You could use as background-color an rgba i.e.

```
.lightbox
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    z-index:1000;
}
```

...and, as a fallback (i.e. for IE :D ) a transparent repeated 1px image

Comment: `background-color:transparent repeated 1px image;` ?

Comment: I tried using IE filters but I get completely transparent background now in IE8 and 7

Comment: no, as fallback u could use an **image** 1px by 1px :) like `background: url(path/to/image) repeat;` before `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9)`

Answer (score 2):

Opacity set on a parent will also affect the opacity of any child elements. The simple solution here is to remove the lightbox image `div` from the parent:

```
<div class="lightbox"></div>
<div class="lightbox-image">
    <p>Something here </p> 
</div>
```

The layout will stay exactly as it was before, but the opacity of the background will now be independent of the image.

Comment: Can't do that. To much of other things involved in that. Thanks though! Any way to do it with jQuery or is it the same thing?